# Facebook javascript sdk and manual login/logout flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a chrome kiosk with a manual facebook share flow. (I can also use the javascript sdk, but still run into the same issue).

In the perfect scenario, a user logs in and authenticates the app. On login/authentication complete, facebook will hit the redirect_uri with an access token.

```
var loginUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
+"client_id=" + facebookId
+"&redirect_uri=" + loginRedirectURI
+"&response_type=token"
```

I can save that access token to logout the user manually:

```
var logoutUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?"
+"client_id=" + facebookId
+"&next=" + redirectURILogout
+"&access_token="+accessToken;
```

Problem:
If the user logs in and then hits cancel or closes out of the window to the permissions/app authorization modal, facebook redirects to the redirect_uri with no access token. As far as I know, I only can logout a facebook user with an access token. Since this kiosk will be public, it's problematic if another user wants to share content and someone else's account is still logged in.

Has anyone used the facebook flow on a public computer and have any suggestions?

Comment: As of right now, I found this chrome extension to clear all cookies on logout/login: https://github.com/jamesdbloom/delete-all-cookies

So far so good.

Comment: Kiosk apps will always be problematic ... having a multitude of users log in on a device they never used before, over a short period of time, is very likely to trigger Facebook’s security algorithms. Consequences can range from mildly annoying to users (having to perform additional steps next time they log in), to getting your app blocked. If at all possible, you should implement device login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices